# nginx gzip not compressing mp4

Tags: nginx, gzip

Any ideas why my gzip conf is not compressing mp4 and jpg?s

nginx.conf includes my gzip file

```
#gzip  on;
include /etc/nginx/gzip;
```

--

```
gzip on;
gzip_http_version 1.0;
gzip_disable     "MSIE [1-6]\.";
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_min_length  1100;
gzip_comp_level 2;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types video/mp4 text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/jpeg;
```

Comment: Compressing mp4 is very likely to result to higher data flow, so I don’t see any reason why you should to compress this kind of already compressed binary data in first place.

Comment: Ths was something i was asked to look into. But as you say, there is no benefit for this idea.